# which webkit does Office 365 uses by default

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

I want to know which webkit is used by Office 365 for rendering the web portion [ both on the task pane as well as the dialogue ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your Mac OS version. High Sierra and later are WebKit 2, before High Sierra it was WebKit 1. The specific build will match your Safari installation.